# How to partly preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, preventdefault

There is a `<label>` with a `<a href="#">` element inside. I'd like to prevent the default behaviour of the `<a>` element (i.e. navigating) but it *should* execute the default behaviour of the `<label>` element (i.e. checking the checkbox inside it).

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/3M6WE/. Clicking `foo` toggles the checkbox. Clicking `bar` does not navigate but neither toggles the checkbox.

How can I have the `<a>` element *not* navigate but *have* it toggle the checkbox? I'd like to avoid hacks like toggling the checkbox manually. I'm looking for a "partly" `preventDefault`, if available.

Comment: Putting an `<a>` inside a `<label>` seems kind-of strange.

Comment: what's the use of the link if clicking 'foo' does exactly the same?

Comment: Agree with @Pointy, what is the purpose of that `<a>` then?

Comment: Good point, I reduced too much. The link in my real app toggles a `<div>` inside that allows the user to enter more details about the option checked.

Comment: Why not just use a span instead of `<a>` ?

Comment: @xdazz: It doesn't quite have the look-and-feel as an `<a>` element. I could of course style the `<span>` but if there is a neat solution to the `preventDefault` issue that would be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could trigger the click of the parent element (the label):

http://jsfiddle.net/3M6WE/11/

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().click();
    // do stuff...
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

then do some magic and finally call preventDefault();

Comment: This is feasible. One quick follow-up question - do you perhaps know why in http://jsfiddle.net/3M6WE/5/ clicking "foo" triggers the label click handler twice?

Comment: @pimvdb The event is still bubbling up to the label, but on one click the default behaviour is prevented.

Comment: @pimvdb, that's because the original, default-prevented event still bubbles up the DOM tree. Calling `stopPropagation()` on the original event before triggering the new one should fix it.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: But clicking the checkbox does not. Am I missing something?

Comment: @pimvdb use `stopPropagation()` or simply `return false` in `<a>` click handler: http://jsfiddle.net/3M6WE/8/.

Comment: @VisioN: I was referring to "foo" not "bar", I'm afraid.

Comment: @pimvdb, clicking the check box does not run the handler, so it does not result in an additional event being triggered.

Comment: The problem @pimvdb is talking about is that when you click on the `label` (*not* on the `a`, and *not* on the `input`), the event handler is executed twice (two messages in console). Adding `stopPropagation` does not prevent that.

Comment: @James Allardice: Indeed, but my bad, clicking text in the label triggers the click event of the checkbox *and* the label. Solved :)

Comment: This answer does NOT work in Safari. See my answer below for a working version.

Comment: @Casey Foster: I'm looking for a Google Chrome solution (I tagged the question as such) - thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: I see, well I'm still a little confused why you'd want to add more code to do the same thing removing code could do =p

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can't prevent this:

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label):

> Click events in nested  elements
>
> Starting with Gecko 8.0 (Firefox 8.0 / Thunderbird 8.0 / SeaMonkey
>   2.5) , a bubbling click event triggers at most one `<label>`, and the synthetic click event cannot trigger additional `<label>`s. In Gecko, a
>   click event will still bubble up past a `<label>`, while in WebKit or
>   Internet Explorer the click event will stop at the `<label>`. The
>   behavior prior to Gecko 8.0 (triggering multiple `<label>`s) caused
>   Firefox to stop responding (see [bug 646157](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646157) ).

Answer (score 2):

How about http://jsfiddle.net/3M6WE/10/? Simplifies your problem by removing the `href='#'`.

Comment: Now there's no link, and no link click event.

Comment: Sort-of works, but still e.g. allows one to select the link text. But it is a feasible solution, so +1.